# parallelism and concurrency in a Orleans grain

Tags: .net-core, orleans

As Microsoft mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/orleans/benefits#single-threaded-execution-of-grains) Orleans grains are Single-threaded execution which means just one request at the same time could be proceeded by grain with the given ID. Meaning if I had this request :

```
IPlayerGrain player = client.GetGrain<IPlayerGrain>(playerId);
```

At the same time, just one request could be responded to. My question is what will happen if, in some concurrent situations, many requests with the same ID are sent to the exact grain simultaneously? should they wait to be proceeded by Orelans one by one? (means a delay in request to the user) or is there any solution to process them simultaneously?

Answer (score 1):

The requests will queue and be processed 1 at a time by the grain. If there is a large number of concurrent requests, then some of them could time out waiting for a chance to execute.

You have a few options to avoid this:

1. Spread the requests out amongst multiple grain ids if possible so reduce the concurrency on a particular grain.
2. Use a StatelessWorker grain instead. Stateless workers will automatically scale out if there are many incoming requests for them
3. Consider marking the grain as [Reentrant] or the interface method as [AlwaysInterleave]. This will permit orleans to run multiple requests against the grain at the same time, which can improve processing throughtput